# How to arrange tikzpictures and tables in arbitrary grid formation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, positioning

Arrangement of the included graphics could be, easily, done by `minipage`, `subfloat` and the other utilities. Here, there is a set of three `TikZ`-generated figures and a table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_0$}; 
        \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_1$}; 
        \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
         edge node {$\beta$} (s_1)  
         (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{1st}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table}
    \begin{tabular}{| c || c | c | c | c |}
        \hline      & $s_0$ & $s_1$ & $s_2$ & $s_3$\\
        \hline $0$  & $s_1$ & $s_1$ & $s_1$ & $s_1$\\
        \hline $1$  & $s_3$ & $s_2$ & $s_3$ & $s_3$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_6$}; 
        \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_4$}; 
        \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
        edge node {$\beta$} (s_1)   
        (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{2nd}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
       \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_08$}; 
       \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_7$}; 
       \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
          edge node {$\beta$} (s_1) 
        (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{3rd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can one arrange tikzpictures and tables in arbitrary grid formation?

For example:

```
[tikzpicture][tikzpicture][tikzpicture]
                [table]
```

,

```
[tikzpicture][tikzpicture]
[tikzpicture]   [table]
```

or any other positioning.

Update:

Here is the current version of the code with `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_0$}; 
        \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_1$}; 
        \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
         edge node {$\beta$} (s_1)  
         (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{1st}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table}
    \begin{tabular}{| c || c | c | c | c |}
        \hline      & $s_0$ & $s_1$ & $s_2$ & $s_3$\\
        \hline $0$  & $s_1$ & $s_1$ & $s_1$ & $s_1$\\
        \hline $1$  & $s_3$ & $s_2$ & $s_3$ & $s_3$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_6$}; 
        \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_4$}; 
        \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
        edge node {$\beta$} (s_1)   
        (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{2nd}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
       \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_08$}; 
       \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_7$}; 
       \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
          edge node {$\beta$} (s_1) 
        (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{3rd}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

There is an error as: `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

Comment: use `subcaption` package

Comment: @percusse: Could you please find the update?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I added `\hfill` after all 4 `\end{subfigure}`s. But the error does still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a `table` inside a `figure`, as they are both floats, although you can easily put `tabulars` in figures and images in tables.

Also, a `subfigure` is just a glorified `minipage`.  You just have to be specific as to what sort of caption you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_0$}; 
        \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_1$}; 
        \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
         edge node {$\beta$} (s_1)  
         (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{1st}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}
    \captionof{table}{Table}
    \begin{tabular}{| c || c | c | c | c |}
        \hline      & $s_0$ & $s_1$ & $s_2$ & $s_3$\\
        \hline $0$  & $s_1$ & $s_1$ & $s_1$ & $s_1$\\
        \hline $1$  & $s_3$ & $s_2$ & $s_3$ & $s_3$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_6$}; 
        \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_4$}; 
        \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
        edge node {$\beta$} (s_1)   
        (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{2nd}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
       \node[state,initial,accepting] (s_0)   {$s_08$}; 
       \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {$s_7$}; 
       \path[->] 
        (s_0) edge [loop above] node {$\alpha$} ()
          edge node {$\beta$} (s_1) 
        (s_1) edge [loop above] node  {$\alpha, \beta$} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{3rd}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks... The first row (including the table and its adjacent subfigure) are not aligned (table is a little lower than the subfigure). Is this something typical, which should be handled with `\begin{aligned}\end{aligned}`?

Comment: Yeah, that one looks better to align centers.

Comment: BTW, do you really want this as two separate figures, or two rows in one figure?

Comment: Actually, they are both two different ways to do this, however I admit that `two rows in one figure` is more reasonable.